# Making GridView items square

Tags: android, gridview

I would like the items of my `GridView` to be square. There are 2 columns and the items width is `fill_parent` (e.g. they take as much horizontal space as possible. The items are custom views.

How do I make the items height to be equal to their variable width?

Answer (score 105):

There is a simpler solution when GridView columns are stretched. Just override the onMeasure of the GridView item layout with...

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: Works great. Just a few things I missed in the answer: 1. The height is ignored and the width is passed as the height. 2. The method should be overridden in the item and the Grid itself.

Comment: About 1: that's what makes it square --"

Comment: Should we extend GridView class to achieve this? If so, I get InflateException. Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu This would be used in the layout of your grid items, not the GridView itself. You could perhaps extend RelativeLayout to SquareRelativeLayout with this snippet.

Comment: Nice approach. Seems to be the right way to get squared views when the grid view is stretching your view width (and not its height).

Comment: if i do that in my gridview, i make the GridView square, not its children.

Comment: what do you mean by "when the columns are stretched"? I have set `numColums=3` but not `stretchMode`, should I? and if yes, to what value?

Comment: A complete answer would be nice. Are you saying to extend gridview?

Answer (score 56):

Or if you want to extend a View just do something really simple  like:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{

    public SquareImageView(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, w, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that `super.onMeasure()` is not needed. `onMeasured` requirement is that you must call `setMeasuredDimension`.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins I disagree with your last comment: if I do not call `super.onMeasure()` , an ImageView placed inside it will not be drawn. So it seem it is required as first line of the `onMeasure` method.

Comment: @nerith, is this on a specific device as I have been using this code for a very long time and never ruin into issues. Interested to see how to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins not on a specific device. My SquareFrameLayout is loaded from the xml. Do you add you children programatically?

Comment: Oh yeah this won't work with view groups only views. Maybe I should mention that.

Comment: More reusable solution, best answer

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure this is possible with the current widgets. Your best bet might be to put your custom view in a custom "SquareView". This view could just contain 1 child view, and force the height to equal the width when its onLayout method is called.

I never tried to do something like that, but I think it shouldn't be too difficult. An alternative (and maybe slightly easier) solution might be to subclass your custom view's root layout (like, if it's a LinearLayout, make a SquareLinearLayout), and use that as a container instead.

edit : Here's a basic implementation which seems to work for me :

```
package com.mantano.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SquareView extends ViewGroup {

    public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int u, int r, int d) {
        getChildAt(0).layout(0, 0, r-l, d-u); // Layout with max size
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        View child = getChildAt(0);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = resolveSize(child.getMeasuredWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        child.measure(width, width); // 2nd pass with the correct size
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }
}
```

It's designed to have a unique child, but I ignored all of the checks for the sake of simplicity. The basic idea is to measure the child with the width/height parameters set by the GridView (in my case, it uses numColumns=4 to calculate the width), and then do a second pass with the final dimensions, with height=width... 
The layout is just a plain layout, which layouts the unique child at (0, 0) with the desired dimensions (right-left, down-up).

And here's the XML used for the GridView items :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mantano.widget.SquareView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/item" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello world" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.mantano.widget.SquareView>
```

I used a LinearLayout inside the SquareView in order to have it manage all the gravity possibilities, margins, etc.

I'm not sure how well (or bad) this widget would react to orientation and dimension changes, but it seems to work correctly.

Comment: That all sounds good, the only problem is to write correctly onLayout (or onMeasure). Currenlty I set height/width in ItemAdapter.getView() but I don't like this solution.

Comment: @anagaf I edited my answer with code I just tested and which seems to work. It's fairly easy to understand, so it should be easy to fix just in case you find some glitches ^^   (not sure if I was supposed to edit or post a second answer, sorry if I did it wrong !)

Comment: The above layout doesn't work --- I don't know why, but there are subtle layout problems with the children that mean that, e.g., TextViews won't wrap and RelativeLayouts get horribly confused. However, I did find an equivalent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948212/android-layout-with-sqare-buttons ...although I still needed to adjust it a bit (it sizes based on the biggest dimension rather than just the width).

Answer (score 13):

It ends up being fairly easy to get the grid item square.

In your "GetView" method of your grid adapter, just do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridView grid = (GridView)parent;
    int size = grid.getRequestedColumnWidth();

    TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
    text.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));

    // Whatever else you need to set on your view

    return text;
}
```

Comment: had to replace "getRequestedColumnWidth" with "getColumnWidth" and it worked for me ..thanks !

Comment: same here: I had to replace `getRequestedColumnWidth` with `getColumnWidth` and worked for me ... thanks!

Comment: For modern usage, make sure to replace `new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size);` with `new GridView.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, size));`

Answer (score 6):

I don`t know if it is the best way, but I accomplish that making my custom view to override onSizeChanged that way:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (getLayoutParams() != null && w != h) {
        getLayoutParams().height = w;
        setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
    }
}
```

I use this custom view inside a LinearLayout and a GridView and in both it is showing square!

Comment: Oh man, you're a life saver, I've been fighting with this for days. Gregory's answer works fine unless you have a lot of children; then, as a comment points out, TextViews don't wrap and most views don't readjust their bounds.

But this fixes it!

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
<GridView
...
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

You can also play with other modes

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me!

If you are like me and you can't use getRequestedColumnWidth() because your minSdk is lower than 16, I suggest this option.

1. in your fragment:

   `DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
   getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
   int size = dm.widthPixels / nbColumns;
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(list, size, getActivity());`
2. in your adapter (in getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent))

   `v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, size));`
3. fragment.xml:

   `<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />`
4. custom_item.xml: (for example)

   `<ImageView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/picture"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop" />`

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 5):

if you set a static number of columns in the xml then you can take the width of the view and divide it by the number of columns.

if you are using `auto_fit` then it's going to be a bit tricky to get the column count ( there is no getColumnCount() method ), btw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912922/android-how-does-gridview-auto-fit-find-the-number-of-columns) question should help you somehow.

this is the code I'm using into the `getView(...)` method of the adapter with a fixed number of columns:

```
    item_side = mFragment.holder.grid.getWidth() / N_COL;
    v.getLayoutParams().height = item_side;
    v.getLayoutParams().width = item_side;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I am doing to show square cells in a GridView. I am not sure if you want square cells or something else.

```
GridView grid = new GridView( this );
grid.setColumnWidth( UIScheme.cellSize );
grid.setVerticalSpacing( UIScheme.gap );
grid.setStretchMode( GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH );
grid.setNumColumns( GridView.AUTO_FIT );
```

And then the view which I am creating for each cell I have to do the following to it:

```
cell.setLayoutParams( new GridView.LayoutParams(iconSize, iconSize) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [SteveBorkman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875315/2823516), which is API 16+:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    GridView grid = (GridView)parent;
    int size = grid.getColumnWidth();

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_item, null);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
    }

     //Modify your convertView here

     return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of @Gregory's answer, I had to wrap my image in a LinearLayout in order to keep GridView from manipulating its dimensions from square. Note that the outer LinearLayout should be set to have the dimension of the image, and the width of the GridView column should be the width of the image PLUS any margin.  For example:

```
    <!-- LinearLayout wrapper necessary to wrap image button in order to keep square;
    otherwise, the grid view distorts it into rectangle.

    also, margin top and right allows the indicator overlay to extend top and right.

    NB: grid width is set in filter_icon_page.xml, and must correspond to size + margin
    -->
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sport_icon_lay"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sport_icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:maxWidth="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the GridView like:

```
   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:columnWidth="66dp"

        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="25dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="24dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"

        />
```

Answer (score -1):

In your activity

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
 valX = displaymetrics.widthPixels/columns_number;
```

in the CustomAdapter of the GridView

```
 v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, YourActivity.valX));
```