# Square items in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I made a `CustomAdapter` to show my items in the `GridView` on a certain way. In that CustomAdapter I override the `getView()` method. The problem is, I want to set the height of my griditems to equal the width of them, which can be different for each smartphone. I saw already a solution, but that didn't work out for me (it said I had to override the onChanged() method in my custom View). Anyway, can anybody put me on the right track on how to deal with this problem?

The code of my xml's/.java file is:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dip"
        android:background="#33c2bd" />

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gvLevelSelector"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:background="#33c2bd">
     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvLevel"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
       android:text="Test here" />
     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvLevelScore"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="15dip"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvLevel"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
       android:text="test2"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom Adapter**:

```
public class LevelSelectorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LevelSelectorItem> {

    public LevelSelectorAdapter(Context C, List<LevelSelectorItem> Arr) {
        super(C, R.layout.levelselector_item, Arr);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mView = v;

        if (mView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }

        TextView level = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel);
        TextView levelScore = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevelScore);

        if (mView != null) {

            level.setText(getItem(position).getLevel());
            levelScore.setText("test");             

        }
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [making grid view items square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557516/making-grid-view-items-square)

Answer (score 0):

Use resources and display metrics.
Set the layout parameters of the view.

You could do this during the onBindView.

Here is a snippet I use:

```
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cocktails_cocktail_tile,this);
    ConstraintLayout rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.cocktailTileRootLayout);
    rootLayout.getLayoutParams().width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
    rootLayout.getLayoutParams().height = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
```