# Android ImageView setting Bitmap FitXY doesn't work

Tags: android, image, imageview, scale, android-imageview

I've been trying for a really long time to set the bitmap so it will fit the `ImageView` bounds.

It just doesn't work via `scaleType: fitXY`. My bitmap images size are lower than the `ImageView`'s (Saved on 100X100 pixels), I want my bitmap images to fit and stretch into the `ImageView`.

Here's some code:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/imageView" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/locked_image"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Here's the code of setting the `ImageView` (I'm setting the `scaleType` in different places for testing):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ImageView imageView;
  if (convertView == null) {
    imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  } else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  }

  imageLoader.displayImage(imagesIds[position], imageView, options);
  imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  return imageView;
}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

**As you can see, the Height of the `ImageView` is fine, but I want the Width of it to be the same.** I do not have access to my bitmap image via my activity, so please don't ask me to resize my bitmap. I really don't understand why it just doesn't work as it should.

---

**EDIT:**
Just to make the problem more understandable. The `ImageView` height is calculated for each device. It is different for each device. I want the width of my `ImageView` to be the same as the height as it is. I am using the `Two-WayGridView` library to show the images if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  What do you mean "I want the Width of it to be the same"?  The same as what?  are you expecting a square image?  Is you image view of square shape?  I don't understand.

Comment: If your ImageView were 100x100, then using fitXY would create a 100x100 image on the screen.  As it is, it looks like you have a 100x200 size ImageView, or some similar thing.

Comment: @HalR I'm expecting a square image, yes. I want the size of the width to be the same as the height.(Bigger). The height of my imageview is scaled automatically - it's totally fine. but the Width, is too low. I want it to be the same as my height. How can I do it? even programatically.

Comment: Your layout is setting the imageview width and height to be the width and height of its parent.  Then fitxy is fitting the image within this box.  If you want the imageView to be 100 by 100, why don't you just set it the xml height and widht parameters to 100dp instead of matchparent?

Comment: @HalR I never said I want my imageview to be 100 by 100. I said I'm saving the bitmap on 100 by 100. The imageview height is calculated for each device. It different for each device. I want the width of my imageview, to be the same as the height as it is.

Comment: Have you tried a grid layout like this:  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/  ?

Comment: @HalR I have been going through this, I'm using the TwoWay Grid View.

Comment: @HalR Ah.. do you have any idea in your mind..? using FITXY should create a Square Imageview and it just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `scaleType` will not change the size of your ImageView, as you seem to think it should. All it does is scale the bitmap up to the size *of* the ImageView(which it is doing quite well, judging by your screenshot).

If you want to make square ImageViews, you should try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6557516/752320).

Also, I'm not sure I understand why you're using the [TwoWayGridView](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) library. It's specifically designed to allow you to state the number of rows/columns, and it will stretch the items to fit. This seems to be the exact opposite of what you want, since you want to make them square. A normal GridView will work, provided you override the `onMeasure()` of each item like it shows in the linked quesion/answer.

Comment: My target is to make the same gallery as the original gallery app. As I understood from their architecture, when the device is in portrait mode, there are 2 rows. and all the displayed images are square. Please, if you can, look at the Gallery to better  understand what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, I know that a normal GridView will work, But I'm looking for a horizontal one :)

Comment: Ah, horizontal. Makes sense for a gallery. Well, the best way to go about it is overriding the `onMeasure` of each item, like I said above. It's simple, only a few lines of code, and has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Actually, I've already tried it, but I'll give it another shot now :)

Comment: WOW, that's just works. I can't believe that!!! So great. I just had to edit the code so that the height will be the same and not the width. :) You're great seriously. I'm so happy right now. I was looking for this kind of solution for a real long time.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder what container widget you use for holding ImageView.
for example... GridView, ListView, etc...
If you use GridView, you try to set count of column by GridView.setNumColumns(). 

If still does not work, you try to use AspectRatioFrameLayout class by one of many way.
this class is simple. follow the steps below!

**1. add attributes in res/attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="AspectRatioFrameLayout">
    <attr name="aspectRatio" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**2. create AspectRatioFrameLayout class**

```
public class AspectRatioFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private static final String TAG = "AspectRatioFrameLayout";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private float mAspectRatio; // width/height ratio

    public AspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AspectRatioFrameLayout);

        mAspectRatio = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.AspectRatioFrameLayout_aspectRatio, 1.0f);

        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "widthMode:"+widthMode+", heightMode:"+heightMode);
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "widthSize:"+widthSize+", heightSize:"+heightSize);

        if ( widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
            // do nothing
        } else if ( widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)(widthSize / mAspectRatio), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else if ( heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)(heightSize * mAspectRatio), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

**3. modify list_item_image.xml**

```
<your.package.AspectRatioFrameLayout       
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:aspectRatio="1">

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/locked_image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
</your.package.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Good answer    android:scaleType="fitXY" .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using src property, Use background property of imageView. Bitmap will be stretched.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageView" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/locked_image"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Comment: You should use android:layout_width="100dp" and android:layout_height="100dp" for exact 100x100 imageview. Thanks!

Comment: From OP's comments: *"I never said I want my imageview to be 100 by 100. I said I'm saving the bitmap on 100 by 100. The imageview height is calculated for each device. It different for each device."*

Comment: instead of using "match_parent", you should use "wrap_content". Then imageView size will be according to your bitmap, And also must use background property instead of src.

Answer (score -2):

Use background with fitxy instead of using src. It will stretch your image:

```
android:background="@drawable/locked_image"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Comment: Use background with fitxy  instead of using src.  it will stretch your image.