# How to set `ImageView`'s height to match it's width while `layout_weight` is set?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, height, width

Here is the deal:
I have a `GridView` with `android:numColumns="2"`. The items in the `GridView` are `ImageViews` with `android:layout_weight="1"`, so they are half the screen width. The problem is the `height`property, it should be equal to the width. I tried to play with `scaleype`, so far without success. 
How can I set the width of the `GridView` elements to fill half the screen and set their height to be equal to their width?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: If I remember right I showed square shaped images in the grid view, so setting their height and width to wrap_content was enough. Otherwise you can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557516/making-gridview-items-square

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the ImageViews width programmatically and then set the height.

But if you just use **`img.getWidth()`**; eg. in `OnCreate()`, it will return `0` because it hasn't been drawn yet.

So you have to do something like this in `OnCreate()`:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img); 
ViewTreeObserver vto = img.getViewTreeObserver();
         vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
             public boolean onPreDraw() {
                 int x;
                 img.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                 x = img.getMeasuredWidth();
                 img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(x,x));
                 return true;
             }
         });
```

This will get your Imageview's width after its been drawn and set its height equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

To set your `ImageView` equal to half the screen, you need to add the following to your XML for the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

To then set the height equal to this width, you need to do it in code.  In the `getView` method of your `GridView` adapter, set the `ImageView` height equal to its measured width:

```
int measuredImageWidth = mImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = measuredImageWidth;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: int the getView method even getMeasuredWidth() return zero.