# How to make perfect squares on android?

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2iW2.png
I want to make the squares on the left, and be able to put text on top, and on the bottom like in the image, it could also be an image instead of text?

I've tried gridlayout and tablelayout and I can't manage to make them perfectly square or to replicat the view.

Can anyone help?

Comment: make a custom container ViewGroup that overrides onMeasure and makes the measured width and height the same

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557516/making-grid-view-items-square